# NullPointerException при повторной передаче данных в сервис

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-intent, activity-service-connection

По нажатию кнопки создаю интент, помещаю в него url потока и запускаю сервис, в котором этот поток воспроизводится, всё ОК. При попытке сделать рестарт сервиса, передав другой url, получаю
 `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`

OnCreate в MainActivity:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    createService = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    destroyService = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    restartService = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    serviceState = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    createService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestService.class);
            intent.putExtra("RadioURL", "http://dorognoe.hostingradio.ru:8000/radio");
            startService(intent);
            serviceState.setText("Service is created");
        }
    });

    destroyService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestService.class));
            serviceState.setText("Service is not created");
        }
    });
    restartService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestService.class);
            intent.putExtra("RadioURL", "http://dorognoe.hostingradio.ru:8000/radio");
            startService(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

onStartCommand в сервисе:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    mp.stop();
    mp.playAsync(intent.getStringExtra("RadioURL"));//тут вылетает исключение
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

Comment: возможно, когда интент совпадает с предыдущим (одинаковые данные в них содержатся), то он приходит пустым. Попробуйте каждый вызов передавать разные параметры, и посмотрите, будет ли он прихождить пустым все равно.

Comment: Возможно, сервис не успевает остановиться и в onStartCommand попадает интент остановки сервиса, в коем нету вашего URL. Попробуйте передавать URL и в интенте остановки сервиса. И в `onStartCommand` проверяйте есть ли `Extras` в интенте.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я нажимаю кнопку createService, а потом сразу restartService, интент остановки сервиса не посылается. Если в рестарте я сначала остановлю сервис и снова запущу, то будет работать. Но мне не подходит вариант с предварительной остановкой сервиса, потому что при быстром многократном нажатии на кнопку restartService предыдущий сервис действительно будет не успевать остановиться, как уже началось воспроизведение  нового потока, и начинается каша из несколько потоков. Кажется, проблема действительно в том, что написал metalurgus в комментарии выше и нужно в интенте давать другое имя url'y.

Comment: Но тогда мне нужно искать другой способ передачи данных в сервис.

Comment: Попробуйте тогда через `Binder` сервис с активити связать. Так вы сможете напрямую вызывать методы экземпляра сервиса. Посылать интент надо будет только при начальном старте сервиса.

Comment: Пустой интент может быть только в случае рестарта сервиса системой (в случае падения сервиса) и дефолтного START_STICKY. Есть подозрение, что вы чего-то не договариваете. Например, загадочный mp может падать на `mp.stop();` с IllegalStateException (как это сделал бы стандартный MediaPlayer), а потом вы получаете пустой интент при рестарте...